# Morphological Hit Miss Transform

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am using OpenCV for my image processing algorithms and am trying to fix up ragged edges in characters. I read that the morphological Hit-Miss transform is a very good solution for this. Is there any open source implementation of this?

Or is there any other algorithm that can be used to fix ragged edges?

[image: Some sample letters that need fixing]

Comment: where have you read? i think that Hit-Miss itself is not enough, you need to use something morphological operation derived from it. see http://www.ee.lamar.edu/gleb/dip/10-2%20-%20Morphological%20Image%20Processing.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation of hit-and-miss can be found [here](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/hit-or-miss-transform-in-opencv/):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

// Hit-or-miss transform function
void hitmiss(cv::Mat& src,    // Source image, 8 bit single-channel matrix
             cv::Mat& dst,    // Destination image 
             cv::Mat& kernel) // Kernel. 1=foreground, -1=background, 0=don't care
{
    CV_Assert(src.type() == CV_8U && src.channels() == 1);

    cv::Mat k1 = (kernel == 1) / 255;
    cv::Mat k2 = (kernel == -1) / 255;

    cv::normalize(src, src, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);

    cv::Mat e1, e2;
    cv::erode(src, e1, k1);
    cv::erode(1 - src, e2, k2);

    dst = e1 & e2;
}
```

But i think that you can solve the problem only with dilation, as the example in [page 7 of this slide](http://ee.lamar.edu/gleb/dip/10-1%20-%20Morphological%20Image%20Processing.pdf) (it is taken from "Digital Image Processing" book from Gonzales et al.)

Answer (score 0):

Combined morphological dilation and erosion using [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) produced the result below:

[image]

Source code:

```
package characterRestoration;

import marvin.image.MarvinColorModelConverter;
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.io.MarvinImageIO;
import marvin.plugin.MarvinImagePlugin;
import marvin.util.MarvinPluginLoader;

public class CharacterRestoration {

MarvinImage                 image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/character_in.png");
private MarvinImagePlugin   dilation = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.morphological.dilation");
private MarvinImagePlugin   erosion = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.morphological.erosion");

private boolean[][]         matrixD = new boolean[][]{
                            {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                            {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                            {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                            {false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
                            {false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
                            {false,false,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
                            {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                            {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
                            };

private boolean[][]         matrixE = new boolean[][]{
                            {true,true,true},
                            {true,true,true},
                            {true,true,true}
                            };          

public CharacterRestoration(){
    // Convert image to binary format
    image = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(image, 125);

    // Morphological Dilation
    dilation.setAttribute("matrix", matrixD);
    dilation.process(image.clone(), image);

    // Morphological Erosion
    erosion.setAttribute("matrix", matrixE);
    erosion.process(image.clone(), image);

    MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/character_out.png");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new CharacterRestoration();
}
```

}